# Need help with ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I need to print out the value of `x, y`, and `z` when `h==0, g==0`. Help please?

```
h = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2; 
g = x^3 + y^2 - z^2;

ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]},
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  ContourStyle ->  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The blue Pringle-shaped curve is when `h==0` and `g==0`.  Otherwise you could use `Solve[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, y, z}]`. ??

Comment: @ChrisK. I knew the blue curve is when h==0 and  g==0, but in other word what are`x,y` values at `z=0` point in the z-axis?

Comment: The question in the comment is not the same as the question in the OP. Could you please edit the question in the OP?

Answer (score 3):

Like Chris says in a comment, `Solve` can be used to find the values where `h == 0 && g == 0`, at least for two variables since we have two equations. You take as an example `z = 0`. For that case we have the following:

```
Solve[h == 0 && g == 0 /. z -> 0, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -1, y -> -1}, {x -> -1, y -> 1}}

Here's a demonstration of finding the values for different `z`:

```
sols[zval_] := Append[zval] /@ Values@Solve[h == 0 && g == 0 /. z -> zval, {x, y}, Reals]

cp = ContourPlot3D[
   {h == 0, g == 0},
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}
   ];

pts = Flatten[Table[Quiet@sols[z], {z, -2, 2, 0.1}], 1];
Show[
 cp,
 Graphics3D[{
   Green, ,
   Sphere[pts, 0.2]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]